# Singleton issues with node libraries that includes the project library

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, singleton

I have a private node library called Utility. This library is also used by my other private libraries (Foo) as well.

When I use Foo in my project, it includes the Utility library in the node_modules of Foo. If I want to use the Utility library and Foo library at the same time, the singleton gets messed up because my project uses the Utility Library's singleton and the Foo library uses its own singleton from its own copy of the Utility Library from Foo's node_modules. Thus breaking the idea of being a single instance.

Is there a workaround to have the Foo library use the project's Utility singleton instead of the one from Foo's node_modules?